# Rails link_to anchor with remote: true & method: :post

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, anchor

The anchor doesn't work with method: :post for some reason.

My view file index.haml:

```
/ some code here
%h3= Description
.results
  =render 'result_box'
```

_result_box.haml partial:

```
.row#scroll-here
  .col-md-12
    = link_to "Get result", get_result_path(@book, :anchor => "scroll-here", parameters: {first: 1, second: 2}), method: :post, remote: true
```

index.js.erb :

```
$('.results').html("<%= j (render partial: 'result_box') %>")
```

After pressing link_to and reloading ".results" the page focus is still on the top of the page. But I want it to be at the "#scroll-here".

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm currently struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @Martin No, sorry

Answer (score 1):

<%= link_to "Get Result", path(id: params[:id]), class: "", method: :post, remote: true %>

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 = link_to "Get result", get_result_path(@book, :anchor => "scroll-here", parameters: {first: 1, second: 2}), method: :post,{ remote: true}
```

or

```
= link_to "Get result", get_result_path(@book, :anchor => "scroll-here", parameters: {first: 1, second: 2}), method: :post,:remote=> true
```

Refer this link (http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#inserting_ruby_)

Comment: Your first option results in error and second one is the same as mine