# How to use Ajax links with anchors in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to create a nav panel that uses AJAX to switch between pages, and can link to anchors on those pages in a Rails 5.1 app.

From what I've read, the following code *should* work, but doesn't.

```
<%= link_to @section.title, from_nav_path(@topic, anchor: @section.css_id), remote: true %>
```

(If it isn't clear already, Topic `has_many` sections, and Section `belongs_to` Topic)

I've read through, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568609/rails-link-to-anchor-with-remote-true-method-post) stackoverflow post, as well as these two  reference pages ([api doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to), and [mix and go](https://mixandgo.com/blog/how-to-use-link_to-in-rails)).

When it's not setup as `remote: true` it works fine through the `show` action, but I don't want to reload the page.

Currently, it does change to the correct page, but it just stays at the top of the page, rather than following the anchor. What am I missing to make this work?

I have also tried adding a javascript callback independently and jointly to the partial to be loaded and the `from_nav.js.erb` file. All to no avail.

Comment: The links in your post have been removed. Please fix them

Comment: Do you have id `@section.css_id` on page before sending the request(click link)?

Comment: @KartikeyTanna Links fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: @ArtemDorodovskyi I'm not sure I understand your question. I need rails to load the partial, and then to jump to `@section.css_id` within that partial. So when you see the `link_to` `@section.css_id` is not yet loaded, because the partial hasn't yet been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use anchor option with remote. An anchor is a piece of text which marks the beginning and/or the end of a hypertext link. But `remote` is a helper method in Rails that add to tag `data-remote="true"` attribute and then Rails know that need to send XHR request. Anchor not working with XHR requests. So, you can add javascript in your `from_nav.js.erb` to [scroll to the element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp)

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("<%= @section.css_id %>");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I wasn't actually able to get `elmnt.scrollIntoView();` to work. From what I read, it may be a conflict with Turbolinks. Unclear. I was however, able to make it work with `window.location = '#<%= params[:scrolltohere] %>';` (and obviously, changing my `link_to` to pass `scrolltohere: @section.css_id`

Comment: Yes, you right. Turbolinks visit does not scroll to in-page anchors and `window.location = '#<%= params[:scrolltohere] %>';` best issue.